# Google Analytics Warnings on iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, google-analytics

Just recently, I started getting new console warnings from the Google Analytics static library for iOS. I only following get the following logs on an actual device, not in the simulator.

`CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'GAIProperty' for entity 'GAIProperty'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'GAIHit' for entity 'GAIHit'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
idfa class missing, won't collect idfa`

Any ideas what those could mean, why they happen and how to possible resolve the issues?

Comment: From @nstefan: Like alistair said, adding the -ObjC linker flag is required. It will also point out the sqlite framework references if you did not add it to your project. Adding the sqlite3 lib removed the CoreData logs but I still have the idfa log: - "idfa class missing, won't collect idfa"

Comment: Adding `libsqlite3` doesn't help with the first warnings but adds the new one: `ld: warning: ignoring file libsqlite3.dylib, missing required architecture x86_64 in file`

Answer (score 11):

The documentation for the latest analytics SDK isn't particularly clear.

If you add the -ObjC flag in "Other linker flags" within your XCode project, it'll fix this issue.

Comment: Sorry, this does not seem to fix the problem for me.

Comment: It didn't work. I only get this error in Today Extension not my own app.

Answer (score 7):

According to this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ga-mobile-app-analytics/hktBHr0sGoU), it's a problem with the SDK but this does not affect the normal operation of the library.
The warnings will be fixed in future updates.

Answer (score 4):

There's a ticket filed for this problem in Google Bug tracker: https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=486

The solution is to **update to version 3.10** which fixed the warning for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:    (From my above comment:) As documented in Implementing Core Data Managed Object Subclasses, you have to prefix the entities class name in the Class field in the model entity inspector with the name of your module, for example "MyAPP.GAIProperty".

Comment: And how can we hide the warnings?